# How to avoid code block splitting over 2 pages with Minted

Tags: page-breaking, minted, python

I was wondering if there is a simple way to insert a page break when a too long Python code has a function splited over 2 pages and won't fit inside current page?
The page break should be placed just before the function.
Assuming Python code is following PEP8.

I have been digging inside a lot of Latex resources but can't find any answer.

Here is a long Python code where a the function **_set_overload** are splited over the next page.

[image]

My Latex code is quite simple :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\inputminted[linenos]{python}{protocol.py}
\end{document}
```

And thus would make the code more legible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You can improve based on the `tcblisting` environment from `tcolorbox` package. It has `breakable` support that can achieve what you want. You just need to customize the appearance.

Comment: Thanks @AlanXiang for your suggestion, I tried **tcolorbox** this way :```\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}[left=2pt, right=2pt, top=2.5pt, bottom=2.5pt]
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\inputminted[linenos]{python}{protocol.py}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}``` But the split is still here

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you wanted to do. You want `minted` to only break at locations that is specified by the user?

Comment: Nope, I want to insert a page break before a Python function when this one won't fit inside the rest of the page (see previous screenshot). And thus avoid a split of the Python function in two parts (rest of the function into the next page) which become difficult to read over two pages. I hope I remove any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

### Manual breaking to prevent page break in functions

It is possible to achieve what you want by changing the internal function `\FancyVerbGetLine` in `fancyvrb`. The code is attached below.

The page break can be triggered by a line in Python that contains the text `#PB####`. I choose this sequence because it will be parsed as comment in Python and it will not interfere with normal execution. An example is shown in `test.py`.

I tried to explain how it works in the comments. If you have any further questions, just let me know.

#### LaTeX Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\makeatletter

% the pygments output for #PB#### is stored here (we use \detokenize{} to convert it to "string")
\edef\fancyvrb@pb@match{\detokenize{\PYG{c+c1}{\PYGZsh{}PB\PYGZsh{}\PYGZsh{}\PYGZsh{}\PYGZsh{}}}}

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active%
\gdef\FancyVerbGetLine#1^^M{%
  \@nil%
  \FV@CheckEnd{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\FV@EnvironName%            % True if end is found
    \ifx\@tempb\FV@@@CheckEnd\else\FV@BadEndError\fi%
    \let\next\FV@EndScanning%
  \else%
    \def\FV@Line{#1}%
    \def\next{\FV@PreProcessLine\FV@GetLine}%
    \edef\fancyvrb@cur@line@detok{\detokenize{#1}}% convert the current fancyvrb line to string
    \ifx\fancyvrb@pb@match\fancyvrb@cur@line@detok\newpage\def\FV@Line{}\fi% if the current fancyvrb line is equal to \fancyvrb@pb@match, insert a page break and empty the line
  \fi%
  \next}%
\endgroup

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\inputminted[linenos]{python}{test.py}


\end{document}
```

#### test.py

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)

p1.age = 40

print(p1.age)


#PB####

class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def myfunc(self):
    print("Hello my name is " + self.name)

p1 = Person("John", 36)

p1.age = 40

print(p1.age)
```

### An automatic approach

One way to do this automatically is to make use of Python's `ast` module to acquire the abstract syntax tree (AST), and use the AST to distinguish function lines and other lines.

The source code is shown as below. The Python script is called with two arguments: `python3 convert_to_tex.py input_py_file output_tex_file`. Python 3.8+ is recommended.

```python
# convert_to_tex.py
import ast
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass

in_fn = sys.argv[1]
out_fn = sys.argv[2]

with open(in_fn) as f:
    src = f.read()

src_lines = src.split('\n')

tree = ast.parse(src)

func_line_nos = []
function_flag = [0] * len(src_lines) # used to avoid repeating segments in nested functions

for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef)):
        if not function_flag[node.lineno-1]:
            func_line_nos.append((node.lineno-1, node.end_lineno-1))
            for i in range(node.lineno-1, node.end_lineno):
                function_flag[i] = 1

@dataclass
class NonFuncSeg:
    data:str
    start: int

@dataclass
class FuncSeg:
    data:str
    start:int

file_seg = []

last_pos = 0
for start, end in func_line_nos:
    if last_pos < start:
        file_seg.append(NonFuncSeg(src_lines[last_pos:start], last_pos))
    file_seg.append(FuncSeg(src_lines[start:end+1], start))
    last_pos = end+1

if last_pos != len(src_lines):
    file_seg.append(NonFuncSeg(src_lines[last_pos:], last_pos))

assert sum(len(x.data) for x in file_seg) == len(src_lines) # make sure we do not miss any lines

with open(out_fn, 'w') as outfile:
    for item in file_seg:
        if isinstance(item, NonFuncSeg):
            outfile.write(
(r'''
\begin{CodeCanBreak}{%d}
%s
\end{CodeCanBreak}
''' % (item.start + 1, '\n'.join(item.data))).lstrip()
            ) 
        else:
            outfile.write(
(r'''
\begin{CodeNoBreak}{%d}
%s
\end{CodeNoBreak}
''' % (item.start + 1, '\n'.join(item.data))).lstrip()
            )
```

This script will separate the Python file into function and nonfunction segments. The two types of segments are placed into two LaTeX listing environments `CodeCanBreak` and `CodeNoBreak`, respectively. You can pretty much guess the purpose of the two listing environments by their names.
The output example is shown as below. Note that the number passed to the listing environment is used to restore the correct line number.

```tex
\begin{CodeCanBreak}{1}
#! /usr/bin/env python3

"""Base16, Base32, Base64 (RFC 3548), Base85 and Ascii85 data encodings"""

# Modified 04-Oct-1995 by Jack Jansen to use binascii module
# Modified 30-Dec-2003 by Barry Warsaw to add full RFC 3548 support
# Modified 22-May-2007 by Guido van Rossum to use bytes everywhere

import re
import struct
import binascii


__all__ = [
    # Legacy interface exports traditional RFC 2045 Base64 encodings
    'encode', 'decode', 'encodebytes', 'decodebytes',
    # Generalized interface for other encodings
    'b64encode', 'b64decode', 'b32encode', 'b32decode',
    'b32hexencode', 'b32hexdecode', 'b16encode', 'b16decode',
    # Base85 and Ascii85 encodings
    'b85encode', 'b85decode', 'a85encode', 'a85decode',
    # Standard Base64 encoding
    'standard_b64encode', 'standard_b64decode',
    # Some common Base64 alternatives.  As referenced by RFC 3458, see thread
    # starting at:
    #
    # http://zgp.org/pipermail/p2p-hackers/2001-September/000316.html
    'urlsafe_b64encode', 'urlsafe_b64decode',
    ]


bytes_types = (bytes, bytearray)  # Types acceptable as binary data

\end{CodeCanBreak}
\begin{CodeNoBreak}{34}
def _bytes_from_decode_data(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        try:
            return s.encode('ascii')
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            raise ValueError('string argument should contain only ASCII characters')
    if isinstance(s, bytes_types):
        return s
    try:
        return memoryview(s).tobytes()
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "
                        "string, not %r" % s.__class__.__name__) from None
\end{CodeNoBreak}
\begin{CodeCanBreak}{47}
```

You can use this generated LaTeX code with `\input` with the appropriate environment definitions:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,minted,breakable}


\begin{document}



\tcbset{
  listingbase/.style n args={1}{
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0.4\baselineskip, % adjust accordingly
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    colback=white,
    boxsep=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    before={\par\noindent},
    frame hidden,
    listing only, 
    listing engine=minted, 
    minted language=python,
    minted options={
        linenos,
        numbersep=0.5em,
        firstnumber={#1}
    }
  }
}

\newtcblisting{CodeCanBreak}[1]{listingbase=#1,breakable,}
\newtcblisting{CodeNoBreak}[1]{listingbase=#1}

\bgroup
\input{example.tex}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan Xiang for your proposal (really appreciated), but it's not answering my first question, having a simple way to insert a page break an top of a too long Python function. May be there no answer, or minted package should be adapted to implement that feature...

Comment: @Nexus1138 I updated the answer with an automatic approach using AST. Hope this achieves what you desired. Sometimes you need to be creative on the Python side.

Comment: Thanks again @AlanXiang for your contribution, I made some test with your script, removing the assert because of error, an output `example.tex` was effectively generated. Then run `$ latex -shell-escape page-break-code.tex`, but the .dvi is not showing any page break. Your solution seems to be a good first step anyway.